# Movie not being shown right in landscape mode when using transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion but does when using addSubview

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4, landscape

I have a movie for a landscape app, and when I just do `[self.view addSubview:movieView]`, it works fine, but when I do `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion`, it is displayed as if it's in portrait mode.  Why is this, and how do I get trasitionFromView to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With transitionToView, you're replacing self.view at the top of the hierarchy, so movieView doesn't inherit the current bounds; i.e. it doesn't know it's in portrait mode.  Try just animating the addSubView:

```
   [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:2 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view addSubview:aViewController.view];
                    } 
                    completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

Without controller you can just use the existing view:

```
   [UIView transitionWithView:fromView
                  duration:2 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [fromView addSubview:toView];
                } 
                completion:NULL];
```